# Unexpected behaviour of class_exist

Tags: theme-development

if translate press plugin active, everything is fine but when it is deactive, I get this error

Call:

> Notice: Undefined index: text-call-header in link/file.php on line 8

I confused because redux and translate press are different plugins.what is the problem?

note: $redux_demo['text-call-header'] is not defined.so I expect the
error about 8. line but why it occurs only when translate press is
disabled?

8th line:

```
echo $redux_demo['text-call-header'];
```

30th line:

```
                    if ( class_exists( 'TRP_Translate_Press' ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown lang-button text-center">
                            <button class="dropbtn color-white">Language</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999!important; padding:unset!important; background-color: #f9f9f9;">
                                <?php echo do_shortcode('[language-switcher]'); ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the full code, but if Redux runs different code if Translate Press is or isn't active then it's perfectly possible for an error to only exist in one of those situations. If there's a problem I suggest speaking to the authors of Redux, as third party plugins are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

For temporary purposes try the below code to avoid error -

```
if(isset($redux_demo['text-call-header']))
{
  echo $redux_demo['text-call-header']; 
}
```

Let me know if need more help.